# scrapy rules generating single link

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to learn scrapy and I am currently trying to parse bbc website.

I feel that I have done everything alright but rules generate only a single link. Here is the code:

```
class BBCSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "bbc"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.bbc.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.bbc.com/news/world",
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"http://www.bbc.com/news/world-.*"),
             callback='parse_item', follow=True)
    ]


    def parse_item(self, response):
        print(response)
```

Currently, only a single link (http://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-33833400) is generated. I have absolutely no idea why. The regex matches a lot more links on the page.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of the links are like this one (with a relative URL):

```
<a href="/news/world-middle-east-33833400" class="title-link">
    ...
</a>
```

Check for the `news/world-.*` only:

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"/news/world-.*"),
         callback='parse_item', follow=True)
]
```

Also, `allowed_domains` should contain the domain:

```
allowed_domains = ["bbc.com"]
```

Comment: Still did not work. I tried a bunch of links to see if the regex matches them, and it does.